# Python: Convert a list into a bidimensional mapping dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[
    {'student_id': 'john', 'exercise_id': '3', 'answer': 20},
    {'student_id': 'john', 'exercise_id': '2', 'answer': 10},
    {'student_id': 'jane', 'exercise_id': '2', 'answer': 30},
]
```

What is an elegant/short way to convert that into a [exercise x student] "mapping table" dictionary? 
Like so:

```
{
    '3':{
        'john': {'student_id': 'john', 'exercise_id': '3', 'answer': 20}
    },
    '2': {
        'john': {'student_id': 'john', 'exercise_id': '2', 'answer': 10},
        'jane': {'student_id': 'jane', 'exercise_id': '2', 'answer': 30}
    }
}
```

You can assume the map contains at most one answer per exercise per student.

Comment: As always, what have you tried?

Comment: Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generates the output you want:

```
output = {}
for value in data:
    output.setdefault(value['exercise_id'], {})[value['student_id']] = value

print output
```

Comment: Instead of calling `setdefault(_, {})` you can use change type of `output` from `dict` to `defaultdict(dict)`, see more in docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 3):

The straight forward way would be to gather them in a dictionary, like this

```
d = {}
for item in l:
    d.setdefault(item["exercise_id"], {}).setdefault(item["student_id"], []).append(item)
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'2': {'jane': [{'answer': 30, 'exercise_id': '2', 'student_id': 'jane'}],
       'john': [{'answer': 10, 'exercise_id': '2', 'student_id': 'john'}]},
 '3': {'john': [{'answer': 20, 'exercise_id': '3', 'student_id': 'john'}]}}
```

First, if the `item["exercise_id"]` is not there in `d`, then a new dictionary will be set as the value and then in that dictionary, if `item["student_id"]` is not there, we set an empty list as the value and we append the current dictionary in that list.

Comment: Upvoted for short answer plus explanation. Will mark friedi's answer as correct though because it produces the exact desired output. Although this construct will probably be useful in the future too. Thanks!!!!